# Which Regex for this language is the "cleanest" or most efficient?

Tags: regex, performance

I am looking for the simplest (most efficient?) regex that will match arbitrary sequences composed of two tokens, A and B, with the restriction that B must appear at least once. I.e., sequences composed only of A should not match. Some matched sequences are B, BA, AB, AAAAABAAAA, ABAAABABABAB, etc.
I've come up with the following regex's. I am curious if there's something even simpler or more elegant which I'm missing? Also, which one will be the most efficient? Thank you!

```
(A|B)*B(A|B)*
(A|B)*BA*
A*B(A|B)*
```

Comment: So `BBBBB` is also a valid match?

Comment: Yes, B+ is a valid match.

Answer (score 2):

The third one is unambiguous and does not require any backtracking.

The second one is also unambiguous, but the `*` after the first expression will cause the engine to skip past the last B, and then it has backtrack to leave one for the match to be successful. (This is more of a practical implementation detail than a theoretical necessity, but this is how regex implementations generally work.)

Anything which can match more than one way is potentially problematic from an efficiency point of view. Google for "catastrophic backtracking".

If you mean to look for a literal regex for either of two letters, the character class `[AB]` will be more efficient than `(A|B)`.

Comment: If the regexps are compiled, do the three still perform backtracking? Shouldn't they all be compiled to a DFA?

Comment: I guess you mean NFA? Most engines don't use NFA; whether it's compiled or not doesn't make a difference really.

Comment: I meant a *deterministic* finite automaton (DFA) but I guess most engines do not use automatons at all regarding your answer, isn't it? Thank you for the information about compilation.

Comment: Sure, a regex engine will basically convert the expression into an automaton, though there is a lot more going on around it with optimizations etc. What I was trying to say is that backtracking is a thing for deterministic search, whereas nondeterministic (NFA) will not need to backtrack because it basically explores everything in parallel and just prunes branches when it realizes something can't match. Whether the regex is compiled or not doesn't change this.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex:

```
^A*B[AB]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PheSvu/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `A*`: Match 0 or more of `A`s
- `B`: Math a single `B`
- `[AB]*`: Match 0 or more of `A` or `B` characters
- `$`: End

---

If your regex engine supports lookahead then you may use this regex with a lookahead condition:

```
^(?=A*B)[AB]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PheSvu/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=A*B)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have at least one B
- `[AB]+`: Match 1+ of `A` or `B` characters
- `$`: End